# Webservice handle more endpoint in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I am developing a web service in Spring boot, the dependency library is spring-boot-starter-web-service. I only want to expose 2 endpoints to get content defined wsdl  **http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl** and **http://localhost:8080/ws2/countries2.wsdl**. However /ws/countries2.wsdl and /ws2/countries.wsdl also can access. How do config to only access as my expect /ws/countries.wsdl and /ws2/countries2.wsdl?

Spring boot version 3.2.0

Below is my source code

1. src/main/resources/countries.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"
           targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="currency">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

2. src/main/resources/countries2.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service2"
           targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service2" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest2">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getCountryResponse2">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="currency">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

3. CountryEndpoint

```
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(
            @RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
        GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
        response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));

        return response;
    }

}
```

4. CountryEndpoint2, i change namespace and localPart

```
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint2 {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service2";

    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryEndpoint2(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest2")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse2 getCountry(
            @RequestPayload GetCountryRequest2 request) {
        GetCountryResponse2 response = new GetCountryResponse2();
        response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry2(request.getName()));

        return response;
    }

}
```

5. WebServiceConfig

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*", "/ws2/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "countries2")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition2(XsdSchema countries2Schema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Countries2Port");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws2");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service2");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countries2Schema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countries2Schema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries2.xsd"));
    }
}
```